# Cisco C3750, detect high traffic

Tags: cisco, network-monitoring

I would like to know what are the interfaces that produce more traffic in my switch.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

While the `show interface <interface>` command will show packet rates over intervals, it is a very blunt tool.  Almost any NMS ([Network Monitoring/Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems)) would be a better solution.  Most will record and graph traffic utilization of an interface over time.  Specific NMS recommendations are off-topic.

I would consider a NMS that supports [Cisco Netflow](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/switch/configuration/guide/fswtch_c/xcfnfc.html).

Netflow enabled interfaces will track the following:

- IP source address
- IP destination address
- Source port
- Destination port
- Layer 3 protocol type
- Class of Service
- Router or switch interface

Not only is traffic rate on the interface recorded, but specific traffic telemetry.

Answer (score 0):

Try `show interface`. This command show all info about all interfaces, there you could check port usage.